# only one auto discount applying when using multiple discounts based on price option

Tags: cividiscount

Use case:

- Price field (used for events of certain Event Type) - drop-down with
  8 options
- 2 autodiscounts - $20 off for the first price option, $35
  off for the other 7 (higher price so want to offer a higher discount)

Issue:

- The $20 autodiscount is getting applied to the first price option
  (GOOD)
- The $35 autodiscount is NOT getting applied to the remaining price
  options (NOT good)

Is this a bug? Config issue on my part? Thank you!

(CiviCRM 5.46.2, CiviDiscount 3.8.5, Joomla 3.10.6)

**$20 discount config:**

[image]

**$35 discount config:**

[image]

**options drop-down - only first option gets autodiscount applied**

[image]

Comment: Happening to me too with  CiviCRM 5.49.1, Wordpress 5.9.3 and CiviDiscount 3.8.5. Not good indeed

Comment: It seems this may require an enhancement. See more here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount/-/merge_requests/271