# Only One Autodiscount is being applied in my event. (CiviDiscount extention)

Tags: cividiscount

I'm having a problem where only one autodiscount is being applied using the CiviDiscount extension.

I'll show my settings to see if anyone can point out a misconfiguration...

**The Price Field:**

[image]
[image]

**Price Options for the Price Field:**

[image]

** The Discount Codes (1 for each radio price option) **

[image]

**Settings for Price Option "One Day Pass"**:
*(this one does not work)*

[image]
[image]

**Settings for Price Options "Two Day Pass"**:
*(this one works)*

[image]
[image]

**This is the result of those settings**

[image]

**I've done some research on the bug...**

-The problem originated here:

https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/issues/145

-And seems to have resurfaced recently:

[only one auto discount applying when using multiple discounts based on price option](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41461/only-one-auto-discount-applying-when-using-multiple-discounts-based-on-price-opt)

I came across this in the code that references the linked git bug report, but `$this->entity_discounts` seems to populate both discounts correctly when logging out the array:

[image]

I'm starting to think that the issue does not exist here anymore, but now exists in `cividiscount_civicrm_buildForm` or `cividiscount_civicrm_buildAmount` in `cividiscount.php` where things are getting built and displayed to the user

Has anyone else come across this bug? Is it a bug? If so, can someone post this bug on their Git Repo? I can't seem to be able to because their repo is "Archived"

Any help would be welcomed. Thanks

Comment: It says at https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount "This project has moved to CiviCRM's Gitlab. lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount/" . Does that help?

Comment: @petednz Thanks, looks like I can post an issue there if it already isn't raised.